# Is there a way to append the values of an attribute to another attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I feel like this is a stupid simple question, but I've been doing so much CSS work lately that I feel a little rusty. So, I have several buttons with classname: and class: attributes. Basically, all I want to do is take the value of the classname attribute and append it to class. Only the buttons with className need their content appended.

```
classname="blah_btn blah_btnGrey" class="blah blah blah foo foo"
```

Would I write something like:

```
if ($('#ui-button').has("className")) {
$(("className").val()).appendTo("class");
```

or something more along the lines of:

```
$("button").each(function() {
//do stuff
```

});

Or am I in the completely wrong ballpark? Once again, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are these attributes or element names? `.has('className')` is looking for a `<className />` element. If you were wanting a "has attribute" test, try [`.is('[className]')`](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, please don't use an attribute call `className`.  That is reserved as the way to address the `class` attribute because `class` is a reserved word in javascript.  So, if you use attributes with names of `class` and `className`, you could end up having a hard time reaching them individually in javascript.  It could be a mess.  Pick a more unique name for the one that isn't actually `class`.

To add the class attribute, you would just use `.addClass()`:

```
$('#ui-button').addClass("blah_btn")
```

jQuery's `addClass() is smart enough to not add it if it's already present.

---

If you want to get an attribute and add it to the actual class, you can do this:

```
$('#ui-button').addClass($(elem).attr("myAttribute"));
```

---

If you just want to add one attribute onto another, you can do this:

```
var target = $('#ui-button');
target.attr(target.attr("myAttribute") + $(elem).attr("myAttribute"));
```

Comment: IE7 doesn't recognize class, which is why I'm using className.

Comment: @The31StReaper - when using jQuery, you can use the class methods so you don't have to address the class attribute directly.  If using plain Javascript, you should never (almost) use `.class` from javscript - always use `.className`.  In your HTML, always use `class="xxx"`.  Your question uses both forms and was very confusing in that regard.  It looked like you thought you had two different attributes.

Comment: I see your point. Sorry, man, I guess I should have clarified further. It's been a long day.

Answer (score 1):

That's what you need ?

```
$.each($('#ui-button.className'), function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    $element.addClass($element.val());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
$('button[className]').each(function(){
   var classNameValue = $(this).attr('className');
   var classValue = $(this).attr('class');
   $(this).attr('class', classValue + classNameValue);
});
```

Comment: But this doesn't do anything.  It just assigns the current objects `className` to itself.

Comment: "Basically, all I want to do is take the value of the classname attribute and append it to class. " It does exactly what the OP stated.

Comment: Now that you've edited it - it is, of course, different.  My comment was correct at the time I posted an hour ago.  Now you're trying to use an attribute named both `class` and `className`.  The OP's question is quite messed up, but from reading their comments, they don't actually want two separate attributes with those confusing names.  The question is quite confusing.